# Why don't my records that my specs generate have valid ID values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

This is how I initialize my instance variables:

```
context "when the inviter is being deleted and invited HAS accepted invitation" do
  before :each do
    @user1 = create(:user, gender: 0)
    @user2 = create(:user)
    @membership1 = create(:membership, member: nil, family_tree: @user1.family_tree, inviter: @user1, invited: @user2, relation: "sister", relative_type: 1)
    @membership2 = create(:membership, member: nil, family_tree: @user2.family_tree, inviter: @user2, invited: @user1, relation: "brother", relative_type: 1)
    @connection = create(:connection, inviter_membership: @membership1, invited_membership: @membership2, inviter_user: @user1, invited_user: @user2, request_status: 1)
    sign_in @user1
  end
```

Yet, when I run this test:

```
  it "should NOT delete the inviter_membership record" do
    inviter_membership = @membership1
    delete :destroy, id: @user1
    expect(Membership.find(inviter_membership.id)).to be inviter_membership        
  end
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Membership with 'id'=1441
```

When I explore my DB at the PRY console that is generated with this test failure, these are my results:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> inviter_membership
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 31704, user_id: 13101, created_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", updated_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13102, relative_type: 1>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership1
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 31704, user_id: 13101, created_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", updated_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13102, relative_type: 1>
```

Not the initial `membership.id: nil` value. I see something similar when I examine my other records:

```
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @user1
=> #<User id: nil, email: "eleanore.keeling@lindgrenhettinger.net", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$lROCfnS8rHf3Y2CKp0Ozw.9zsqa4rXTmxU6QvpGUm9S...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", updated_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", first_name: "Murphy", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:56", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "a", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Facere consequatur odio recusandae aut ipsa repudi...", last_name: "Haag", gender: 0, birthday: nil>
[6] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @user2
=> #<User id: nil, email: "dillon.feest@jacobson.biz", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$ju0c8gr/RUaPeRNneh5rVOAN3QtUoMEzy9UwM4.a.D3...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", updated_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", first_name: "Neva", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:56", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "voluptatem", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Reiciendis optio mollitia et vel. Adipisci odit el...", last_name: "Rippin", gender: 1, birthday: nil>
[7] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership2
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 31706, user_id: 13102, created_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", updated_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", relation: "brother", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13101, relative_type: 1>
```

Not sure if it has to do with saving, but the weird thing is that my `@connection` value actually has a valid id:

```
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @connection
=> #<Connection id: 1892, membership_id: 1441, sent_at: "2016-01-23 01:58:47", responded_at: "2016-02-12 11:17:20", send_limit: 5, times_sent: 1, removed_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", created_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", updated_at: "2016-01-28 20:46:58", request_status: 1, invited_membership_id: 1442, invited_user_id: 13102, inviter_user_id: 13101>
```

The only thing I can think of, is in my code, I actually call `connection.update(...)` on the equivalent of this `@connection`. So maybe that call saves the record?

If that's the case, either how do I save my records in Rspec (and do I want to??) or how do I find that record in the database? I need to verify that it hasn't been deleted.

**Edit 1**

If I use `build` in my `@membership1` initialization instead of `create` and dig into it deeper, this is what I get:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership1
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 31799, user_id: 13146, created_at: "2016-01-28 21:08:09", updated_at: "2016-01-28 21:08:09", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13147, relative_type: 1>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> inviter_membership
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 31799, user_id: 13146, created_at: "2016-01-28 21:08:09", updated_at: "2016-01-28 21:08:09", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13147, relative_type: 1>
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership1.valid?
=> true
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership1.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fbd2f9fb458
 @base=
  #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 31799, user_id: 13146, created_at: "2016-01-28 21:08:09", updated_at: "2016-01-28 21:08:09", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13147, relative_type: 1>,
 @messages={}>
```

**Edit 2**

So here is the weird thing, I put a `binding.pry` in the `before :each` at the top to just check the values that are generated before it sends execution to each `it` block. Those values DO have IDs.

```
  51:         @membership1 = build(:membership, member: nil, family_tree: @user1.family_tree, inviter: @user1, invited: @user2, relation: "sister", relative_type: 1)
    52:         @membership2 = create(:membership, member: nil, family_tree: @user2.family_tree, inviter: @user2, invited: @user1, relation: "brother", relative_type: 1)
    53:         @membership3 = build_stubbed(:membership)
    54:         @connection = create(:connection, inviter_membership: @membership1, invited_membership: @membership2, inviter_user: @user1, invited_user: @user2, request_status: 1)
    55:         sign_in @user1
 => 56:         binding.pry
    57:       end
    58: 
    59:       it "should confirm that inviter_membership has nil member_id" do
    60:         expect(@user1.inviter_memberships.first.member).to be nil
    61:       end

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership1
=> #<Membership id: 1474, family_tree_id: 31878, user_id: 13183, created_at: "2016-01-28 21:37:38", updated_at: "2016-01-28 21:37:38", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13184, relative_type: 1>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership2
=> #<Membership id: 1473, family_tree_id: 31880, user_id: 13184, created_at: "2016-01-28 21:37:38", updated_at: "2016-01-28 21:37:38", relation: "brother", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13183, relative_type: 1>
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership3
=> #<Membership id: 1007, family_tree_id: 1001, user_id: 1003, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, relation: "possimus", member_id: 1006, invited_id: 1005, relative_type: 0>
```

However, in the `it` block I am concerned with, it seems to override the `id` value of each instance variable except for one I just added with the `build_stubbed` method rather than `create`:

```
    71:         inviter_membership = @membership1
    72:         delete :destroy, id: @user1
 => 73:         expect(Membership.find(inviter_membership.id)).to be inviter_membership
    74:       end
    75: 
    76:       it "should create a member record with inviter_user's info" do
    77:         expect {
    78:           delete :destroy, id: @user1

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Membership with 'id'=1478
from /gems/activerecord-.1.14/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:320:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership1
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 31886, user_id: 13187, created_at: "2016-01-28 21:38:23", updated_at: "2016-01-28 21:38:23", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13188, relative_type: 1>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership2
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 31888, user_id: 13188, created_at: "2016-01-28 21:38:23", updated_at: "2016-01-28 21:38:23", relation: "brother", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13187, relative_type: 1>
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership3
=> #<Membership id: 1021, family_tree_id: 1015, user_id: 1017, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, relation: "at", member_id: 1020, invited_id: 1019, relative_type: 0>
```

What could be overriding the `id` value within the `it` block?

**Edit 3**

So something strange is happening with the authentication.

If I do `sign_in @user2`, then the test that is failing now passes.

This is the test that fails with `sign_in @user1`, but passes with `sign_in @user2`:

```
  it "should NOT delete the inviter_membership record" do
    expect {
      delete :destroy, id: @user1
    }.not_to change(Membership,:count)
  end
```

I tried commenting out the `sign_in` line altogether, and that also causes the above test to pass.

What's strange is that on my `user` model, I have a `before_destroy :callback`, and when I place a `binding.pry` in that method it doesn't execute on that test, for both a failing and passing test. So it seems that the callback is not being called, which is super strange.

Comment: Can you try the factory for membership1 with build and then call membership1.valid? followed by membership1.errors ?

Comment: @PeterdeRidder Done. I updated the question with the result.

Comment: You could disregard my first comment, because FactoryGirl's create would have raised an error already if the factory could not be created. Unfortunately, I have no time to look into it is, but from a short glance it makes now sense that you use build, create and build_stubbed for 3 memberships. You should use create if you want to query on memberships.

Comment: A smalle note regarding the overriding of the id: Every time the before each block is run you start with an empty memberships table and create new memberships. For each example (it) you have 3 new membership ids. Regarding build, build_stubbed and create in FactoryGirl, only create stores the object in the database. So if you have any queries, you should use create, because otherwise the records cannot be found. Another tip: If you want to know which objects persisted, simply call Membership.all.map(&:attributes) in your example.

Comment: Yeh...I was using primarily `create`, but I began exploring others because you suggested `build` :) I will try that suggest re: Membership.all.

Comment: Also the weird thing is even though I use `create` in one of the assignments, when I do `Membership.all` I get an empty array. So bizarre.

Comment: I'm at work, but if you have an example app in github I can clone it and fix it for you in the evening. If I can reproduce the problem I can explain it what is going wrong.

Comment: I don't have an example app, unfortunately :( But I did update the question with more results of my continuous debugging.

Comment: I think this is the problem: You can't destroy a user and its associated membership if the user is currently logged in. You should be able to reproduce this in development mode.

Comment: @PeterdeRidder Ahh interesting. But Devise does allow you to do that. The only way to actually destroy the user is by logging in with their account and then 'cancelling' it, while logged in. It then destroys the session, destroys the account and redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is the answer and correct explanation, but the errors that Rspec was throwing at me are finally fixed.

I believe what is happening is that in the `before :each` it successfully creates and saves the object to the DB. But, when the spec fails....it basically 'builds' the object and shows me that rebuilt object AFTER the spec failed. So that's why I don't see an `object.id`.

I believe that's the case because if I put a regular `binding.pry` inside each unit test that doesn't fail and then I query the instance variables initialized in the `before :each`, it looks normal. For instance:

```
  it "should NOT delete the inviter_membership record" do
    sign_in @user2
    binding.pry
    expect {
      delete :destroy, id: @user1
    }.not_to change(Membership,:count)
  end
```

Results in this:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @user1
=> #<User id: 13667, email: "cale@stehr.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$h.2yrLwRb1J1uJoWtFKUOuG.IW.UnchqXbfC7v.bJic...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", first_name: "Daisy", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:10", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "vel", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Maxime vitae dolorem atque perferendis sed fuga. A...", last_name: "Rohan", gender: 0, birthday: nil>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @user2
=> #<User id: 13668, email: "ashley_lockman@carroll.net", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$x3XvAGUAaxE0Kk8mtgcFCOb7FrGnPc3IS0wET/xauQU...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", first_name: "Elliott", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:10", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "ducimus", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Aperiam ut quia ea inventore non ad. Nobis nisi di...", last_name: "Hickle", gender: 1, birthday: nil>
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership1
=> #<Membership id: 1747, family_tree_id: 32888, user_id: 13667, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13668, relative_type: 1>
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership2
=> #<Membership id: 1748, family_tree_id: 32890, user_id: 13668, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", relation: "brother", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13667, relative_type: 1>
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @connection
=> #<Connection id: 2351, membership_id: 1747, sent_at: "2016-01-25 01:35:36", responded_at: "2016-02-07 13:16:04", send_limit: 5, times_sent: 1, removed_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", created_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:27:12", request_status: 1, invited_membership_id: 1748, invited_user_id: 13668, inviter_user_id: 13667>
```

It is only if the spec fails, that it shows me the non-persisted objects like so:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected #count to have changed, but is still 2
from /gems/rspec-expectations-3.2.1/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:29:in `fail_with'
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @user1
=> #<User id: nil, email: "maurine.abbott@heaney.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$9AJpP7/UwUDoYMw/YrSd2O2qy.nSZguZGnlWyNt8mVV...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", first_name: "Ashtyn", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:20", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "doloribus", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Perspiciatis dolor natus ut incidunt aperiam culpa...", last_name: "Jones", gender: 0, birthday: nil>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @user2
=> #<User id: nil, email: "scotty.dooley@metz.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$ReYuDORNmKSNeDEYPZrmwuFHPfkv2JWypPQjmKuQVuy...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", first_name: "Albin", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:20", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "dolores", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Rerum soluta dolorum harum rerum fuga repudiandae....", last_name: "Dooley", gender: 1, birthday: nil>
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership1
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 32975, user_id: 13708, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", relation: "sister", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13709, relative_type: 1>
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @membership2
=> #<Membership id: nil, family_tree_id: 32977, user_id: 13709, created_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", relation: "brother", member_id: nil, invited_id: 13708, relative_type: 1>
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DELETEDestroy::WhenTheInviterIsBeingDeletedAndInvitedHASAcceptedInvitation>)> @connection
=> #<Connection id: 2375, membership_id: 1763, sent_at: "2016-01-25 00:35:20", responded_at: "2016-02-20 13:06:58", send_limit: 5, times_sent: 1, removed_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", created_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", updated_at: "2016-01-30 22:28:22", request_status: 1, invited_membership_id: 1764, invited_user_id: 13709, inviter_user_id: 13708>
```

I still don't understand why the last instance variable - `@connection` - is persisted properly while the others aren't....alas....it works properly for me now.

I hope this helps someone!